# Include mediaItems in GraphQL Wordpress query search

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql

I have a headless WordPress installation, and using a React frontend to query posts with a search query of:

```
  posts(where: {search: $searchStr}) {
    nodes {
        title
        content
        link
    }
  }
```

but would like to include media files in the search results as well. I'm able to query and log out the mediaItems from the following additional query:

```
  mediaItems {
    nodes {
      title
      sourceUrl
    }
  }
```

but unable to figure out how to include these in the search results. How do I combine the `posts` and `mediaItems` in the same search query and return all results based on the search string?

**Updated with full query**

The full query I'm using, passes the search query into the posts GraphQL query. Since `mediaItems` and `posts` are both top level in WordPress, how can I combine the two queries so that all posts and all media items are returned based on the search parameter?

```
query appQuery($searchStr: String) {
  posts(where: {search: $searchStr}) {
    nodes {
        title
        content
        link
        tags{
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
    }
  }
  mediaItems {
    nodes {
      title
      sourceUrl
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another GraphQL `type` for that & nest it in your main `type` so that you can also query your data. Also add resolver for that data to be retrieved.

For example: let's say you have a blogging site & you have some posts. For that

```js
type Post {
  _id: String
  title: String
  credit: PostCredit # Name of nested type
}
```

```js
type PostCredit {
  authorId: String # You can also perform further nesting
  publicationId: String
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not sure how the above suggestion would work with my implementation. I have updated my question with my full search query, but not sure how to integrate the `mediaItems` query with the `posts` query, so that they are both used when searching the content.